# Upload ionic app itunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I'm trying to upload my application to connect itunes but I could not get. Valid from XCODE application without any problem, it also raises and spends the whole process normally. But over 1-2 minutes since connect receive an error, error that appears in iTunes do not understand.

```
ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed
```

This message appears next to the binary version of iTunes Connect a red alert icon.

I'm working with this application IONIC, it had already risen above versions without any problem to store.

I cleaned the project, it has made new applications in my environment itunes but nothing works for me. I'm not receiving any specific error. As I said earlier binary is validated from xcode.

Comment: have you got any solution? I am facing same problem.

Comment: have you got any solution? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is mainly due to a plugin in particular, it was the PushNotification plug, take it away and I could upload my application without any problem. Now, there was never notice from Apple, nor stand that there was a problem with this. It was a matter of luck remove this plugin and it work.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: I also have the same issue

Comment: I also have the same issue ... it was long time in processing status ... now it is show as ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed. note I dont use any PushNotification plug.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: There is something odd going on, either at iTunes or with ionic plugins. Please see this thread https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/important-all-ionic-users-please-update-your-keyboard-plugin/46889 -- doing that however did not help with this error so far

Comment: Yes, disaster avoided. started working for me too - I guess it was an iTunes glitch.

Comment: yep, iTunes  issue , now it is working without any change ... but wasted 3h for find solution for this issue

Comment: I have several applications with Push Notifications and none had trouble making the update, but this problem I stand for long, opting for the option to remove the plugin, however if you have worked for them, I think the problem happens by itunes, since not even an error in validating the application from XCODE or not when up to itunes